# Invalid Attempt To Call Read when reader is closed .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I currently have a DB library used for database access and I use it across several projects. I currently use the following code to get a recordset.

> METHODS

```
    public static IDataReader GetRs(string sql)
    {
        using (var con = NewSqlConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            return GetRs(sql, con);
        }
    }
    public static IDataReader GetRs(string sql, SqlConnection dbconn)
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbconn))
        {
            int tries = 1;

            while (tries <= 3)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dbconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        dbconn.Open();
                    }

                    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    myTable.Load(reader);

                    return myTable.CreateDataReader();

                    //return cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.Contains("Timeout expired") || ex.Number == 1205) // Deadlock 
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        if (tries == 3)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }

                        tries += 1;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout *= 10;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Could not get RecordSet");
    }
```

> USAGE

```
public static void Test()
{
    using(var reader = GetRs("SELECT Col FROM TABLE"))
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // do stuff with data here e.g. var value = reader[0];
        }
    }
}
```

While this method works, as you can see it loads the entire dataset into memory thus causing issues with scaling.

I tried replacing the following code in the `GetRs(string sql, SqlConnection con)` method

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

myTable.Load(reader);

return myTable.CreateDataReader();
```

and tried returning just the `return cmd.ExecuteReader();`

However an error is thrown on the `while (reader.Read())` - `Invalid attempt to call read when the reader is closed`. I am guessing this is because the SqlConnection property is disposed (and hence closed) after returning the IDataReader.

I'm aware that I can wrap the `GetRs` method with a new sql connection but this means rewriting a lot of my code, and I was hoping that I would be able to dispose the reader AND the connection with my `using(var reader = GetRs())` method.

Is there any way I can still use these methods without loading the whole dataset into memory?

Comment: If possible you can consider using a library for SQL handling such as EntityFramework

Comment: Why do you want to return a `IDataReader` from your repo layer? Iterate through your reader and populate actual classes and return that.

Comment: Don't use using as it will be disposed, maybe sooner than what it takes to load the records. Consider using EF/Dapper, they both have lazy loading.

Comment: Are the connections being closed and disposed promptly?

Comment: You have a lovely DataTable. Why not return that instead of recreating a reader? You can move through a DataTable in both directions at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject in your code with a `Action<DataTableReader>` parameter to you `GetRs` call.

Try this:

```
public static void GetRs(string sql, Action<DataTableReader> consumer)
{
    using (var con = NewSqlConnection())
    {
        con.Open();
        GetRs(sql, con, consumer);
    }
}

public static void GetRs(string sql, SqlConnection dbconn, Action<DataTableReader> consumer)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbconn))
    {
        if (dbconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            dbconn.Open();
        }
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        myTable.Load(reader);
        consumer(myTable.CreateDataReader());
    }
}
```

(I removed your `try`/`catch` code for clarity.)

Then you call it like this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    GetRs("SELECT Col FROM TABLE", reader =>
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // do stuff with data here e.g. var value = reader[0];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your connection object was closed by the following line

```
using (var con = NewSqlConnection())
{
    con.Open();
    return GetRs(sql, con);
}//Connection object gets released here
```

But still, you are returning the reader object which was created by SqlCommand object using the above connection object. Hence the reader object is closed.

Comment: The OP already knows this. He's said so. His question is "Is there any way I can still use these methods without loading the whole dataset into memory?"

Comment: My bad, i totally missed that part. Need to be careful in future to avoid getting downvoted.